# List all values if value exists multiple times and if one condition per criteria is met

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c05ce02007af16cf61626ad69a39830b)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    supplier VARCHAR(255),
    supplier_rating VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(campaign, supplier, supplier_rating, quantity)
VALUES 
("C001", "Supplier_A", "high", "300"),
("C001", "Supplier_D", "high", "420"),
("C001", "Supplier_F", "mid", "200"),

("C002", "Supplier_A", "high", "180"),
("C002", "Supplier_D", "high", "612"),
("C002", "Supplier_F", "low", "367"),

("C003", "Supplier_L", "low", "763"),
("C004", "Supplier_G", "low", "478"),
("C005", "Supplier_B", "mid", "125"),

("C006", "Supplier_Z", "mid", "136"),
("C006", "Supplier_M", "low", "247"),
("C006", "Supplier_C", "high", "496");
```

**Expected Results:**

```
    campaign     |     supplier      |     supplier_rating
-----------------|-------------------|-----------------------------
    C002         |    Supplier_A     |        high
    C002         |    Supplier_D     |        high
    C002         |    Supplier_F     |        low
-----------------|-------------------|-----------------------------
    C006         |    Supplier_Z     |        mid
    C006         |    Supplier_M     |        low
    C006         |    Supplier_C     |        high
```

---

In the above example I want to query campaigns that 
a) have **multiple suppliers** and 
b) if **at least one of those suppliers** has `supplier_rating` `low` the **campaign should be listed with all corresponding suppliers.**

---

I tried to go with htis query:

```
SELECT 
campaign,
supplier,
supplier_rating
FROM operations
WHERE campaign IN 
      (SELECT 
      campaign 
      FROM operations 
      WHERE supplier_rating = 'low');
```

It almost gives me the expected result but it does not exclude `C003` and `C004`. 
Basiclly, condition `a)` is not considered.

How do I need to modify my query so condtion `a)` and condition `b)` are displayed in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming suppliers are unique for a campaign, then window functions are a simpler solution:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY campaign) as num_supplier,
             SUM(supplier_rating = 'low') OVER (PARTITION BY campaign) as num_low
      FROM operations o
     ) o
WHERE num_supplier > 1 AND num_low > 0;
```

Or you can use aggregation to define the campaigns and then use `IN`, `EXISTS`, or `JOIN` to get the original rows:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM operations o
WHERE o.campaign IN (SELECT o2.campaign
                     FROM operations o2
                     GROUP BY o2.campaign
                     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND SUM(supplier_rating = 'low') > 0
                    );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=35edd5cb55adafdb4f7ec1385858dc90) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: For my own documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0e8b3443c32842c36d6fd4e43c79274f

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most performant query but this one should do the trick :

```
SELECT campaign, supplier, supplier_rating
FROM operations
--Has at least one 'low' rating
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT campaign FROM operations WHERE supplier_rating = 'low')
--Has mulitple campain
AND 1 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM operations op2 WHERE op2.campaign = operations.campaign);
```